# GCP IAP for GKE ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, identity-aware-proxy

After enabling IAP for GKE backend service, getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS because the 302 response generated by the IAP with header `X-Goog-Iap-Generated-Response: true` has the location same as the application URL instead of the auth login/consent screen URL

I have followed https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto

- Auth consent screen configured
- Client ID and Client secret generated correctly when I enabled IAP for the service
- IAP status shows as enabled for the service

Any idea how to fix or debug this?

Is there any way to get logs for IAP proxy requests?